# How to convert tensorflow's BatchNormalization to pytorch?

Tags: python

```
BatchNormalization(axis=3, epsilon=1e-05, momentum=0.1)
```

I want to convert this tensoflow code to pytorch, but pytorch does not have axis, how should I convert it?

Comment: Is that normalization along only a single axis? Try https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#normalization-layers

Comment: Integer, the axis to be normalized (usually the feature axis). For example, set axis=1 in BatchNormalization after a Conv2D layer with data_format="channels_first". However, pytorch does not allow you to specify an axis.

Comment: Perhaps try [`LayerNorm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html#torch.nn.LayerNorm).